# How to refresh my list view children automatically to update children in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I want to make the listview.builder refreshes and updates automatically whenever I add to the apartmentupdate list, You can check below for my current code structure any other idea on refactoring the code structure is also welcomed thanks in advance.

```
class CheckInUpdateLogCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckInUpdateLogCard({super.key});

  @override
  State<CheckInUpdateLogCard> createState() => _CheckInUpdateLogCardState();
}

class _CheckInUpdateLogCardState extends State<CheckInUpdateLogCard> {
  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  late StreamController<List<String>> _activityTextController;
  late Stream<List<String>> activityTextStream;
  final List<String> apartmentUpdate = [
    'Slavador',
    'Cusco',
    'Helsinki',
    'Suzda',
    'Slavador',
    'Cusco',
    'Helsinki',
    'New',
    'New',
  ];

  // @override
  // void initState() {
  //   super.initState();
  //   activityTextStream = getActivityText();
  // }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _activityTextController = StreamController<List<String>>();
    updateActivityText();
  }

  // Stream<List<String>> getActivityText() async* {
  //   while (true) {
  //     await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  //     _activityTextController.add(apartmentUpdate);
  //   }
  // }

  void updateActivityText() async {
    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
      setState(() {
        _activityTextController.add(apartmentUpdate);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _activityTextController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 500,
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: AppColors.greyBackgrond,
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          const ApartmentText(
            theText: 'Recent Activities',
            theColor: AppColors.headerColorBlack,
            theSize: 20,
          ),
          kSpacerHeight30,
          StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
              stream: _activityTextController.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: AppColors.greyBackgrond,
                    color: AppColors.mainAppColor,
                  ));
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final textData = snapshot.data!;
                  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                    _controller.animateTo(
                      _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                      curve: Curves.easeOut,
                    );
                  });
                  return Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        controller: _controller,
                        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: textData.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              ActivitiesText(theText: textData[index]),
                            ],
                          );
                        })),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Text('No Data');
                }
              }),
          kSpacerHeight20,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ActivitiesText extends StatelessWidget {
  const ActivitiesText({
    Key? key,
    required this.theText,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String theText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 40,
      width: double.infinity - 40,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 15,
        bottom: 5,
        right: 5,
        left: 10,
      ),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40, bottom: 15),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColors.mainAppColorLighter,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            topRight: Radius.circular(10),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
          )),
      child: Text(
        '$theText Occupied',
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          color: AppColors.headerColorBlack,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to make the listview.builder refreshes and updates automatically whenever I add to the apartmentupdate list, You can check below for my current code structure any other idea on refactoring the code structure is also welcomed thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you currently add a new item to the apartmentUpdate list, a redraw occurs with the _activityTextController.add(apartmentUpdate) call. However, for StreamBuilder to redraw, there needs to be a change to the StreamController. You can update your code as follows:

```
class _CheckInUpdateLogCardState extends State<CheckInUpdateLogCard> {
final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

late StreamController<List<String>> _activityTextController;
late Stream<List<String>> activityTextStream;
final List<String> apartmentUpdate = [
'Slavador',
'Cusco',
'Helsinki',
'Suzda',
'Slavador',
'Cusco',
'Helsinki',
'New',
'New',
 ];

 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
_activityTextController = StreamController<List<String>>.broadcast();
updateActivityText();
}

void updateActivityText() async {
 while (true) {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  setState(() {
    _activityTextController.add(apartmentUpdate.toList());
   });
 } }// ...}
```

In this example, we changed the type of _activityTextController to StreamController<List>.broadcast(). This allows us to add multiple listeners to the same stream. Then, we used apartmentUpdate.toList() to create a copy of the list. This way, when we add it to _activityTextController, we create a new list without affecting the original one.

With these changes, a situation is provided where StreamBuilder redraws on every update, and ListView.builder is automatically updated.

Comment: I made the adjustment as described above but still no effect after modifying the apartmentUpdate list